# idea on drop down menus, need suggesstions

Tags: php, html

I want to display only a selected choices from all the choices in a drop down box with respect to the choice selected in the previous drop down box...

EXAMPLE:

- DropDown1 contains `living`, `non living`
- DropDown2 contains `Animals` `Birds` `Fruits` `Vegetables`, but the    condition that this drop down has to show `Animals`&`Birds` option only if `Living` is selected in DropDown1 and vice versa
- DropDown3 contains list of `animals`, `birds`, `fruits` and `vegetables` and it has to display only the choices with respect to the Selected option in DropDown2...

Is this possible?

Comment: Please follow below link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405077/show-second-dropdown-options-based-on-first-dropdown-selection-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show second dropdown options based on first dropdown selection jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405077/show-second-dropdown-options-based-on-first-dropdown-selection-jquery)

Comment: yes it is possible, but you need javascript for that as the others mentioned.

Comment: can anyone pls provide a sample code of this example

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

keep disable dropdown3 until user select options from dropdown2, when user select options from dropdown2 make an array or list of data selected by user in dropdown2 or the data you want to display in dropdown3 and apply/notify to the dropdown3 once user set selection to dropdown2