# How can I show a select dropdown menu based on the first select dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I hope I don't bother you all with my question, because I am relatively new to jQuery and JavaScript and I don't know much about it.

I want to make a select dropdown menu. If the user has selected a value from the select dropdown menu, then there comes a new select dropdown menu based on the chosen value, like websites about car vehicles where you choose (for example), a BMW and then you get to see a new dropdown menu, where you can choose out of the models of the BMW cars.

Sorry for any grammatical mistakes. I am dutch.

I hope that you can help me with this. As i said, I am new to jQuery and JavaScript and I hope someone can explain it well.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, because i don't study any study related to computer science. I love to learn something within computer science. I already know xhtml(5) and css(3).

Comment: The best thing you can do is have a go at it yourself then come back here and post your code and someone may be able to advise you on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are more than willing to guide, but give us something to go on other than a rough idea and no code.

Comment: Where will you get the data for the next dropdown from? A json object? A dropdown already (hidden) on the page?

Comment: You should tell us what you've tried already!

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

first you have a problem with your code  because checkname can be undefined  and he cant use test function there.

Both of your dropdowns should have an id.

I suggest you to check first if the checkname is not undefined then do the next validation

```
$( "#target" ).select(function() {
  // do the call to ajax and popualte the next dropdown
});
```

For more information you can visit http://jqapi.com/#p=select
Also you can learn more about ajax here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

A similar post [How to populate a cascading Dropdown with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351921/how-to-populate-a-cascading-dropdown-with-jquery)

Have a good day

Comment: If the OP is really as new to jQuery as implied, this is probably well beyond their depth, and the OP says nothing about loading data via AJAX. Not saying your answer doesn't have merit, but it is likely not applicable to the OP's knowledge so far and doesn't provide enough of an example to be useful by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code below allows user selection of a drop-down id="division" to re-populate a drop-down id="branch_no".  Notice the method jQuery.getJSON - that's making an AJAX call to a PHP page that does the query and returns JSON data.

```
$('#division').change(function() { 

    jQuery.getJSON( 'gAjaxJsonBranches.php?division=' + $('#division').val(), null, function(jdata) {

        var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON(jdata);

        var $el = $("#branch_no");
        $el.empty();

        $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').html('&lt;&lt;SELECT&gt;&gt;'));

        $.each(jObj.searches, function(key, value) {
            $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value['id']).text(value['item']));
        });
    });


 });
```

Code for gAjaxJsonBranches.php, uses a database lookup:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdb', 'user', 'password');

$search_list = '{ "searches": [ ';

$l_sql = "SELECT b.branch_no, b.branch_name " ;
$l_sql .= "FROM branches b INNER JOIN divisions d ON b.divisions_id = d.id " ; 
$l_sql .= "WHERE d.division = '" . $_GET["division"] . "' " ; 
$l_sql .= "ORDER BY b.divisions_id, b.branch_no ";

foreach ($conn->query($l_sql) as $l_row) {

    if(trim($l_row[1]) != '') {

        $search_list .= '{' ;
        $search_list .= '"id": "' . $l_row[0] . '",' ;
        $search_list .= '"item": "' . $l_row[0] . '-' . $l_row[1] . '"' ;
        $search_list .= '},' ;
    }

}

$search_list = substr($search_list, 0, -1);

$search_list .= '] }';

header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo json_encode($search_list);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dwsx/)**

Given an array of values such as:

```
var mainDropdownValues = {1: "one", 
                           2: "two",
                           3: "three",
                           4: "four"};
```

and with a helper function such as:

```
var assignValuesToDropDown = function( dropdownSelector, valuesArray ){
    var seloption = '';

    $.each( valuesArray, function(index, value){            
         seloption += '<option value="'+ index +'">'+ value +'</option>';
    });

    $(dropdownSelector).append(seloption);        
};
```

You can do this to populate the first drop down when the page is ready:

```
$().ready(function(){
    assignValuesToDropDown( "#mainDropdown", mainDropdownValues );

    // add a listener for when the value change on the main dropdown, to update
    // the second one.
    $('#mainDropdown').on('change', function(){
      // need to get the second set of values from somewhere (see demo for how I did it) 
      assignValuesToDropDown( "#secondaryDropdown", dropDownValues );         });
});
```

Comment: the fiddle has a bug where it does not reset the secondary dropdown after each selection; not sure I need to correct it here but it would be something to add if I were you.