# I want that when I select a city of a state, then all the detials of that city are visible

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want that when I select a city of a state, then all the detials of that city are not visible. how to visible it on select city.

I want that when I select a city of a state, then all the detials of that city are visible.

Comment: We can't help if you don't post any relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: What have you tried?? and post the data too.

Comment: Wow you have just copied the same sentence 3times.... what do you expect?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Cascading-Dependent-Dropdown-Chained-Selects.html

or

[How to populate a cascading Dropdown with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351921/how-to-populate-a-cascading-dropdown-with-jquery)

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: And rather than linking to another SO question, flag it as a duplicate.